# Trouble extracting td values from php xpath parsed table html string

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have the following html string snippett from a wikipedia page...

```
<table class="wikitable">
<tbody>
 <tr>
     <td>mod_access</td>
     <td>Versions older than 2.1</td>
     <td>Included by Default</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td>mod_actions</td>
     <td>Versions 1.1 and later</td>
     <td>Included by Default</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>mod_alias</td>
    <td>Versions 1.1 and later</td>
    <td>Included by Default</td>
 </tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I have the following php code....

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
$url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Apache_modules";
$dom=new DomDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
$dom->loadHtmlFile($url);
$xpath=new DomXpath($dom);
$elements=$xpath->query('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td');
foreach($elements as $i=>$row){
    $tds=$xpath->query('td',$row);
    foreach($tds as $td){
       echo "Td($i):", $td->nodeValue,"\n";
    }
}
```

What i'd like in return is a numerical array with each index a `table row filled with the td values`.

Not quite sure what to do next.

Comment: So you're essentially trying to replicate the table? Shouldn't you initially query the table rows (`tr`) instead of the individual cells? Your initial `$elements` contains all of the cells, not all of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove both `tbody` and `td` from your first xpath query, it will find all of the `tr` elements:

```
$elements = $xpath->query('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table/tr');
```

Then you can loop through each row, use your existing code to find `td` elements, and add them to an array:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($elements as $y => $row) {
    $tds = $xpath->query('td', $row);
    foreach($tds as $x => $td) {
        $data[$y][$x] = $td->nodeValue;
    }
}
var_dump($data);
```

Tested with php 5.6, gives this output:

```
array(157) {
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "mod_access"
    [1]=>
    string(23) "Versions older than 2.1"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "Included by Default"
    [3]=>
    string(26) "Apache Software Foundation"
    [4]=>
    string(27) "Apache License, Version 2.0"
    [5]=>
    string(71) "Provides access control based on the client and the client's request[2]"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "mod_actions"
    [1]=>
    string(22) "Versions 1.1 and later"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "Included by Default"
    [3]=>
    string(26) "Apache Software Foundation"
    [4]=>
    string(27) "Apache License, Version 2.0"
    [5]=>
    string(62) "Provides CGI ability based on request method and media type[3]"
  }
// etc ...
```

Comment: works perflectly. not sure though why it was important to remove those queries?

Comment: The `tbody` didn’t appear to be in the HTML source of the page, I had to remove it to be able to find any rows at all. The `td` was removed as your first query only wants to find rows, so that your second query can then find the cells inside each row.